# How to change the "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80" line in Apache?

Tags: apache2

When I open the browser and I go to *localhost* in my web-browser, and there is not an *index.** file the Apache webserver will show a file browser.

At the end of the file browser, it posts this line:

```
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Is there any way to change this message, and if so, where can I find the configuration file that creates this message in **Ubuntu 14.04.01**?

I have searched on Google for some time but I can't find anything that points me in the correct direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all set server signature to off, by setting:

```
ServerTokens ProductOnly
ServerSignature Off
```

in `httpd.conf` file. If you want a custom page than use `ErrorDocument XXX /path/to/page.html` to set different pages. For example: `ErrorDocument 403 /error/denied.html`

Comment: Thanks but I had to edit the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file because I can't find the `httpd.conf`. I added both lines and the message was gone, so I just left the `ServerTokens ProductOnly` in my config file. 

I'm happy with the result though, thanks!
It also seemed to solve my problem with the virtual hosts, by accident haha! Thank you!

Comment: The setting is system-wide, so will affect every vhost as well. :)